# Find general solution to PDE using characteristic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Just want a check to a question I've attempted. I have to find a general solution to this pde using the characteristic equation:

$ \frac{∂u}{∂x} - 4\frac{∂u}{∂y} - 3u = 0$

So I set $a=1, b=-4$ and $c=-3$ and got the characteristic coordinates:

$ξ = ((-4-\sqrt{19})x-y), η = (-4+\sqrt{19})x-y) $

And for the general solution I just put those two into $f_1(ξ) + f_2(η)$. Would appreciate any help on whether this is correct and if not, how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Find a general solution of pde:
$$\frac{∂u}{∂x} - 4\frac{∂u}{∂y} - 3u = 0\qquad(1)$$
We substitute
$$u=ve^{3x}$$
For $v$ we get equation
$$\frac{∂v}{∂x} - 4\frac{∂v}{∂y} = 0\qquad\quad(2)$$
Characteristic equation is
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-4}$$
It solution is
$$4x+y=C$$
Then solution of $(2)$ is
$$v=f(4x+y)$$
and general solution of $(1)$ is
$$u=f(4x+y)e^{3x}$$